# Python. Django. Change feeds of form from get_context_data in CreateView

Tags: python, django, forms, class

I have an issue with my Create view. I initialise it like this:

```
class OutputCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'rcapp/common_create_update.html'
    form_class = OutputForm
    model = Output
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OutputCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # self.form_class.fields['activity_ref'].queryset = Activity.objects.filter(rc_ref=ResultsChain.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['rc']).pk)
        context['is_authenticated'] = self.request.user.is_authenticated
        return context
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # code code code
        return redirect("/portal/edit/" + str(self.kwargs['rc']) + "/#outputs-table")
```

I have a ForeignKey Field in my model and I wanted to filter options for current view.

My form is set like this:

```
class OutputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Output
        fields = ['value', 'activity_ref']
        widgets = {
            'value': forms.Select(choices=(#Choises here 
            ,), attrs={"onChange":'select_changed()', 'class':'selector'})
        }
```

I need to change a queryset for the activity_ref field.
You can see a commented line in get_context_data, it's where I tried to do this. But it didn't work. How can I get what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the choices / queryset to your form.

in OutputCreateView

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs)
    filter_key = self.kwargs['rc']).pk
    return {'filter_key': key}
```

Like this, it will give an error in when your form gets created, because of the unexpected argument. To get around that and to make use of it, override the **init** method.

In your OutputForm

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    kwargs.pop('filter_key')
    super()._init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['value'] = forms.Select(queryset=Activity.objects.filter(rc_ref=ResultsChain.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['rc']).pk), 
                                        attrs={"onChange":'select_changed()', 'class':'selector'})
```

You don't need to set the widgets value, as it is being done in the **init** method.

Comment: Can you help me one more time please. I get an error that '__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'' in super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Are you doing the pop() as the first line of the __init__?  

You need to remove any extra kwrags that you passed in before you call he super().__init__().